# where in the script I should enable the camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NaviMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject target;
    public ObjectsManipulation om;
    public float moveSpeed = 1f;
    public float maxFallSpeed = 2f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 1f;
    public GameObject player;

    private Rigidbody rigid;
    private bool OnTheGround = false;
    private Waypoints waypoints;
    Camera navicam;

    void Awake()
    {
        rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();  //get the rigidbody that attached to the object
    }
    void Start()
    {
        waypoints = GetComponent<Waypoints>();
        navicam = GetComponent<Camera>();
        navicam.transform.rotation = transform.rotation;
        navicam.transform.forward = transform.forward;
    }
    void FixedUpdate()  //physic should be done in FixedUpdate not Update
    {
        if (DetectInteractable.detected == true && ItemAction.move == true)
        {
            transform.parent = null;  //disconnect the object for it's parent
            om.stopRotation = true;
            rigid.isKinematic = false;
        }
        if (om.stopRotation == true && ItemAction.move == true)
        {
            navicam.enabled = true;
            if (rigid.velocity.sqrMagnitude > maxFallSpeed) //check if it's falling to fast
            {
                rigid.velocity *= 0.99f; // falling to fast, so reduce speed,  you may want to play around with this number.
            }
            else // if not falling to fast add force to make it fall faster
            {
                rigid.AddForce(Vector3.down * moveSpeed);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.transform.name.Contains("Floor"))
        {
            OnTheGround = true;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (OnTheGround == true)
        {
            ItemAction.move = false;
            rigid.isKinematic = true;
            waypoints.enabled = true;
            player.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the line where I enable the camera:

```
navicam.enabled = true;
```

The problem is that the camera enabled after the transform is already on the floor(ground).

And I want it to be enabled true once the transform start moving down. But I'm not sure where in the script it's making it moving.

The transform have a Rigidbody component attached.

The ItemAction is script that all it does is setting the move to true:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ItemAction : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool move = false;

    public void ItemMove()
    {
        move = true;
    }
}
```

And then I'm checking for action with this script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DetectInteractable : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam;
    public float distanceToSee;
    public string objectHit;
    public bool interactableObject = false;
    public Transform parentToSearch;
    public static bool detected = false;

    private RaycastHit whatObjectHit;
    private bool clickForDescription = false;
    private int layerMask = 1 << 8;
    private GameObject objectWasHit;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            clickForDescription = true;

            if (whatObjectHit.collider != null)
                ExecuteActions(whatObjectHit.collider.gameObject);
        }

        Debug.DrawRay(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward * distanceToSee, Color.magenta);
        if (Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward, out whatObjectHit, distanceToSee, layerMask))
        {
            objectWasHit = whatObjectHit.collider.gameObject;
            detected = true;
            objectHit = whatObjectHit.collider.gameObject.name;
            interactableObject = true;
            print("Hit ! " + whatObjectHit.collider.gameObject.name);
        }
        else
        {
            detected = false;
            clickForDescription = false;
            print("Not Hit !");
        }
    }

    private void ExecuteActions(GameObject go)
    {
        var ia = go.GetComponent<ItemAction>();
        ia.ItemMove();
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (clickForDescription == true)
        {
            ProcessOnGUI(parentToSearch);
        }
    }

    void ProcessOnGUI(Transform parent, int level = 0)
    {
        foreach (Transform child in parent)
        {
            if (child.GetComponent<ItemInformation>() != null)
            {
                ItemInformation iteminformation = child.GetComponent<ItemInformation>();
                if (child.name == objectHit)
                {
                    var centeredStyle = GUI.skin.GetStyle("Label");
                    centeredStyle.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperCenter;
                    GUI.Box(new Rect(
                          Screen.width / 2 - 50 + 20 * level, // <== INDENTATION
                          Screen.height / 2 - 25, 100, 50),
                        iteminformation.description, centeredStyle);
                }
            }
            // Process next deeper level
            ProcessOnGUI(child, level + 1);
        }
    }

    public class ViewableObject : UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
    {
        public string displayText;
        public bool isInteractable;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to save last Y position and current Y position , and you compare them ? If lastYposition > currentYposition then you admit that the transform start moving down?

Comment: What does `if (om.stopRotation == true && ItemAction.move == true)` mean?

Comment: Based on what you're saying, the camera should be enabled if it's not rotating and also it's moving. Your code is doing so, but probably some other parts of your game is setting the `om.stopRotation` to false. You need to use the debugger and step through the execution to make sure `om.stopRotation` is still true by the time it gets to this line `if (om.stopRotation == true && ItemAction.move == true)`

Comment: If you open up the console do you ever see the line `print("Hit ! " + whatObjectHit.collider.gameObject.name);` when pressing the mouse button?

Comment: The problem was that by mistake I started the game when the camera is already enabled true. Once starting the game when the camera is off enabled false it's working fine. I also changed the falling down speed from 0.99f to 0.01f : rigid.velocity *= 0.01f; Now it's working like I wanted.